# WPF ComboBox Binding to Enumeration

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, selecteditem, itemssource

I have a Combo Box that has ItemsSource Bound to an Enumeration using ObjectDataProvider, and its SelectedItem Property is bound to a property of a businessobject.
For some reason it's binding SelectedItem first and ItemsSource second, therefore overwriting my default on the businessobject property. Any ideas why and possibly a fix?
Thanks in Advance.

XAML:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Units">
     <CollectionViewSource.Source>
          <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetNames" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
               <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <x:Type TypeName="BO:Unit"/>
               </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
          </ObjectDataProvider>
     </CollectionViewSource.Source>
</CollectionViewSource>

<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="80"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Units}}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Unit}"/>
```

Comment: May be this will help: [WPF ObjectDataProvider - Binding Enum to ComboBox](http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/11/wpf-objectdataprovider-binding-enum-to-combobox.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it's working fine so I don't think that order of the Bindings is your problem. One thing I noticed is that you're using `GetNames` as the MethodName for the `ObjectDataProvider` so the `ComboBox` ItemsSource will be a Collection of strings and not of the enum `Unit`. If this is your intention then the Property `Unit` should be of type `string`

**Example**

```
public class NamesViewModel
{
    public NamesViewModel(string unit)
    {
        Unit = unit;
    }
    public string Unit
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

If you change `GetNames` to `GetValues` it'll work for a Property of enum type `Unit`

**Example**

```
public class ValuesViewModel
{
    public ValuesViewModel(Unit unit)
    {
        Unit = unit;
    }
    public Unit Unit
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: omg it took me so long to try to debug this. Thank you very much, it works perfectly now.